# Dictionary is returning empty value; but it's still stored in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, beautifulsoup

So I have a method that retrieves data using BeautifulSoup; it's able to store and append the data gathered from the dictionary; however when I try to print the list in order to check data; it returns as

> Empty { }

Sample Code

```
main_link = 'Sample Link'
def_list = []
def_dict = {}

def retrieve_from(ml):
#some code

scrape_data = retrieve_from(main_links)

def MethodA(className, url_link):
    try:
        for div_tag in url_link.find_all('div'):
            div_text = div_tag.find('div', {'class': className})
            if div_text :
                def_dict = {
                    'Description': div_text.text.replace("\n", "")}
                def_list.append(def_dict )
        return def_dict 
    except:
        def_dict = None
```

The method has no problem retrieving data because it prints in the list; when i print the `def_list` in command:

```
 {'Description': 'a'},
 {'Description': 'b'},
 {'Description': 'c'}
```

I;ve tried referencing with the following; but to avail it didn't really solve the issue I had.

I've tried to

```
my_dict = list(def_dict.keys())
pprint(my_dict)
```

but still returns {}, am I pointing to an undefined list?

Comment: You have two entirely unrelated variables in your program named `def_dict` - a global one which never has anything added to it, and a local one within `MethodA()`.

Comment: what output are you expecting in def_dict?

Comment: @jasonharper that's what I was thinking; but why isn't the global - `def_dict` not being accessed? should I change the variable name and return that; and then storing it into the global dict? What would you recommend.

Comment: @nishant the output im expecting is to return 

`{'Description': 'data'},{;Description':'Data'}`

but there's no data being stored; when i try to print it. Hence the problem; but like **jasonharper** said; I am having two entirely different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jasonharper in the comments is right about the problem and LearningNoob basically has a correct solution (with a minor tweak), but I figured it was worth posting to provide the whole picture.

`def_list` is a list defined in the outer scope and is intended to hold `def_dict` dictionaries.
`def_dict` is defined right below it: it's not obvious what this is for immediately, but within `MethodA` we can see that a `def_dict` appears to be intended to be a container with a `Description` key with value based on the text in `<div>` elements of a specific class.

Within `MethodA` we use a series of methods to find `<div>`'s that meet a specific criteria. When we find one, we **create a new `def_dict`**:

```
def_dict = {'Description': div_text.text.replace("\n", "")}
```

Because we are assigning to the variable `def_dict` within an inner scope, this new object (initialized with `{}`) effectively takes precedence over the `def_dict` defined in the outer scope: there are two dictionary instances in memory- within the outer scope, the initial, empty dictionary instance is still assigned to `def_dict` while within the inner scope `def_dict` now references the dictionary `{'Description': div_text.text.replace("\n", "")}`.

This second instance, therefore, is appended to `def_list`. Because `def_list` has not been assigned to within the inner scope, it is still the same list instance we initialized in the outer scope.

When we return to the outer scope, we find that the references to `def_list` and `def_dict` has never changed in these scopes, however the `def_list` still has references to all of the `def_list` instances we created in `MethodA`. Therefore, `def_list` prints a list of `def_dict`s initialized when we ran `MethodA` and `def_dict` prints empty (because nothing was ever added to it).

As it stands, as far as I can tell, there is no why to determine which `def_dict` (of the infinite number of `def_dicts` that `MethodA` could initialize) *should* be referenced by `def_dict` in the outer scope, so I'm not sure of why it is relevant whether `def_dict` returns empty or returns an arbitrary member of `def_list`.

---

Touching on the reason LearningNoob's solution returns `None`, it would likely be because of these lines right here:

```
def MethodA(className, url_link):
    try:
        for div_tag in url_link.find_all('div'):
            [etc]
        return def_dict
    except:
        def_dict = None
```

During `MethodA`'s iteration of `for div_tag in url_link:` it presumably fails at some point. When this happens, the `except` clause is called and `None` is returned implicitly. Therefore, if you do either:

```
def_list = MethodA(*args,**kw)
## or
print(MethodA(*args,**kw))
```

The result will be `None`.

Comment: I see where was my mistake and understand the scenario much clearly; I'm still learning, but nevertheless it's a valuable insight you've given. For now I'll try approaching it differently; because as you said the reason it's printing `None` is due to the `except` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
main_link = 'Sample Link'
def_list = []
def_dict = {}

def retrieve_from(ml):
#some code

scrape_data = retrieve_from(main_links)

def MethodA(className, url_link):
   try:
        for div_tag in url_link.find_all('div'):
             div_text = div_tag.find('div', {'class': className})
             if div_text :
                def_dict['Description'] =  div_text.text.replace("\n", "")
                def_list.append(def_dict )
        return def_dict 
   except:
        def_dict = None
```

Comment: sadly; it returns None as well; but data's are still stored in the list ~ so; it's either my method is not accessing the var; like @jason has said earlier in the comments;

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the list instead of the dictionary?

```
def MethodA(className, url_link):
   try:
        for div_tag in url_link.find_all('div'):
             div_text = div_tag.find('div', {'class': className})
             if div_text :
                def_dict['Description'] =  div_text.text.replace("\n", "")
                def_list.append(def_dict )
        return def_list #instead of def_dict?
   except:
        def_dict = None
```

Comment: I have; as stated which returns the output. But if I tries to print the list; it's return as `None`